# Info extraction - htmls

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I have a bunch of HTML files with the same setup. From these (local stored HTMLs) I would like to extract the yellow marked fields ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvPXh.png)).
As text (only div part i am interested in), total html can be found on dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uka24w7o5006ole/transcript-86-855.html?dl=0

```
<DIV id=article_participants class="content_part hid">
<P>Redhill Biopharma Ltd. (NASDAQ:<A title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/rdhl" symbolSlug="RDHL">RDHL</A>)</P>
<P>Q4 2014 <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">Earnings</SPAN> Conference <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f38686">Call</SPAN></P>
<P>February 26, 2015 9:00 AM ET</P>
<P><STRONG>Executives</STRONG></P> 
<P>Dror Ben Asher - CEO</P>
<P>Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations</P>
<P>Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer</P>
<P><STRONG>Analysts</STRONG></P>
```

I don't know much from Python, but i think with Beautiful soup this should be douable, but i am stuck.
What i've got so far is:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/out'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
```

My output should be a csv file with:
Name of executive / Function of executive / Symbol ticker / Period

Comment: Can you share input html file as text not as image.

Comment: @Alderven done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code extracts the text from the positions that are yellow.

I think the easiest way to do it is using XPath. As far as  know bs4 doesn't support XPath so the code uses lxml. I hope this difference works fine for you. The output file is called eggs.csv

In order to make it work for you, change the directory variable.

*This works for windows. In other platforms you must change the form of the "directory" variable.

```
import textwrap
import os
from lxml import html
import csv

directory=r"C:\Users\Anita Pania\Desktop"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            page=f.read()
            tree = html.fromstring(page)
            y1=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[1]/a/text()"))
            y2=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[2]/text()"))[0]
            y3=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[5]/text()"))
            y4=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[6]/text()"))
            y5=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[7]/a/text()"))
            #soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Name of executive', y3])
    filewriter.writerow(['Function of executive', y4])
    filewriter.writerow(['Symbol ticker', y1])
    filewriter.writerow(['Period', y2])
    filewriter.writerow(['Other', y5])
```

Comment: i have python 3.7 on windows, so your code should work right? @Phineas

Comment: i get the following error:   File "C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\SeekingAlpha\retrieve text.py", line 6
    directory=r "C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/out"
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1].
My source files is the following:  dropbox.com/s/uka24w7o5006ole/transcript-86-855.html?dl=0

Comment: Try substituting / with \ .  You might also need to specify the .html?dl=0 instead of .html, but I am not sure.

Comment: your output after substituting / with \ ?

Comment: File "C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\SeekingAlpha\retrieve text.py", line 6
    directory=r "C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/out"
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]

Comment: i made some changes with the directory (i moved all the files to C:\) and now its error is gone. But now i have a new error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\retrieve text.py", line 14, in <module>
    y2=(tree.xpath("/html/body/div/p[2]/text()"))[0]

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: This is script line is written for the second yellow element of the example - a line that has at least 2 text elements in the p tag. For this I used the [0] which indicates an array. If you have variant types of this p element ( with 1 text element) this line can't work for you. I suggest you eliminate it and try to just think of another pattern or give more examples. Also the script needs some changes in order to print the data from all files. Currently it eliminates the previous data when it writes so you can see data only from the last file. Sorry for that...